# Dumpbin.exe, editbin.exe package needed in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, build-tools

I did a reasonably complete installation of Visual Studio 2019 but am missing tools like dumpbin.exe and editbin.exe which I had in Visual Studio 2017. (Missing meaning: Not callable in developer command prompt, also cannot be found on HD using tools like everything.)

According to MSDN, they have a section named "Additional MSVC build tools", but I cannot make anything out of that when looking at the Visual Studio installer. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/editbin-reference?view=vs-2019 )

Which package/component am I missing during setup?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Eventually (loathing the 1GB+ download/install) I tried it, and now I got it at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\Hostx64\x64\editbin.exe
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Had to get editbin.exe installed temporarily to modify rdcman.

Comment: In my case the path is 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\Hostx64\x64`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does work, however, I did encounter an issue with installing the MSVC build tools. If anyone is using Visual Studio 2022, these are the steps that helped me

- Open Visual Studio Installer
- Select Modify
- Select Individual Components and then search for MSVC
- Select these three options: MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ ARM build tools (Latest);MSVC v143 - VS 2022 x64/x86 build tools (Latest);MSVC v143 - VS 2022 x64/x86 Spectre-mitigated libs (Latest)

[image]

[image]

Thereafter, select modify and let visual studio installer install these components.
Once the installation is done, you will need to add the path to your environment variables.
The executable path for the editbin and dumpbin should be located in this location

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\vc15\VC\bin
```

Add in the file location to the environment variables

[image]

Once the path has been added. Open your solution again and build the project.
The issue should now be resolved